# MassTransit - InMemoryTestHarness and Priority Messaging

Tags: c#, masstransit

We've decided to enable priority queuing on one of our queues. The implementation of this is straight forward and the code change is small,  so we are pretty happy with this feature.

The issue i am having are with the unit test around the consumer. We use the Mass Transits InMemoryTestHarness.
When it hits the SetPriority method is throws an System.ArgumentException 'The RabbitMqSendContext was not available'.

```
await context.Publish(message, c => { 
    c.RequestId = requestId; 
    c.SetPriority(priority); //throws exception here
});
```

We had the same issue when we started using a direct exchange for another queue, but we are able to move the configuration of that into code into configuration of the bus, using the  UseRoutingKeyFormatter method in the RoutingKeyConventionExtensions.

Is there something similar for priority queueing?
Or is there a way i can keep this code and still use the InMemeroryTestHarness?

Comment: Using Masstransit 5.2.1

Comment: I just added `bool TrySetPriority(...)` versions of these methods that don't fail if it isn't RabbitMQ..

Comment: nice one, that will be neater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority queues are a feature of RabbitMQ, and they are not implemented by the in-memory transport. So tests are not going to be able to access the broker-specific features.

If you look at the `SetPriority` call, it is calling GetPayload, which throws an exception if the payload type doesn't exist. You could change your logic to attempt to set it, if available.

```
if(c.TryGetPayload<RabbitMqSendContext>(out var rc))
    rc.BasicProperties.Priority = priority;
```

That way it won't fault on the test, but will do as expected with RabbitMQ.